# GE Predix's machine learning (anomaly detection) capabilities

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, anomaly-detection

**Background:**
I am investigating time-series anomaly detection for industrial machine data, and have stumbled upon [GE Predix](https://www.ge.com/digital/predix). It seems like a promising tool, however, I am not familiar with their approaches for anomaly detection.

**Question:**
Does anyone have experience with [GE Predix](https://www.ge.com/digital/predix), in the anomaly detection space? How would one rate its anomaly detection capability? What technical approaches (algorithms) does it use? Any other literature about [GE Predix](https://www.ge.com/digital/predix) that is openly available that I have missed (besides References below)? Are there any available benchmarks (e.g., versus [Splunk + Prelert](https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/1306/#/overview))? Who are its competitors?

**References:**
1) https://www.predix.com/sites/default/files/predixplatformbrief-march_2016.pdf
2) https://www.predix.com/sites/default/files/GE-Software-Modernizing-Machine-to-Machine-Interactions.pdf

Answer (score 3):

(full disclosure, I do work for GE)

GE itself has been using their GE Predix Anomaly detection algorithms to establish a relationship between anomalies & machine failure for their factories, in an effort to establish a preventive maintenance framework. The algorithms have been heavily tested to catch any point anomalies from a machine data.  Go ahead and test it out for your datasets: The algorithms are available for registered developers (in catalog) to use in their applications.

Technical approaches (algorithms): Univariate/Multi-variate anomaly detection algorithms.  It detect Shift anomalies , Unexpected trends in physical system behaviors, Anomalous patterns & detect changes in relationship among different variables. It also detects data with very high dimensions (>100). Mann-Kendall, Mann-Whitney, Kernel density estimate etc are some of the key algorithms used.

Comment: Thank you, @Lothar, this is helpful. The references I have above seem to be at a very high level with minimal technical material; Do you know of any published comparisons of GE Predix's capabilities (algorithm performance, comparisons, etc) in literature? Something like [Numenta's NAB results](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1510/1510.03336.pdf) would be great.